# Grails - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError after adding dependency http builder

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, groovy

i´m running

```
grails 2.2.3
```

on tomcat6

when i add dependency of groovy http-buidler to my build-config.groovy

```
dependencies {
   ...
   runtime 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.0-RC2'
   ...
}
```

it wont compile anymore with following stack:

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
ERROR  error, Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteGenerator.compileStaticMethod(CallSiteGenerator.java:231)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.createStaticMetaMethodSite(CachedMethod.java:264)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.createStaticMetaMethodSite(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:111)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createStaticSite(MetaClassImpl.java:2993)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallStaticSite(CallSiteArray.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:144)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at org.grails.plugin.resource.CSSRewriterResourceMapper.<clinit>(CSSRewriterResourceMapper.groovy:24)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GrailsApplicationFactoryBean.java:79)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:589)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:69)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:593)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
ERROR  error, Context initialization failed
```

so searching for this issue, brings up there is an incompatibility of asm and hibernate

what i am after is a simple solution,

i rather want to have a dependency that works with my setup, than updating sth. i know tomcat6 is pretty old and grails 2.2.3 is not newest, but is there any way to use groovy http-builder with my setup ?

for any help thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `http-builder` seems to be ancient.

I'm using this one:

```
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7'
```

and have no problems with Grails 2.3.* and 2.2.*

Answer (score 1):

May I recommend a superior http client?

http://grails.org/plugin/jersey-request-builder

It was developed by my old team mates at Rackspace, runs on Jersey client, and it's ridiculously easy to use.

It uses DSL's.  For example:

```
new RequestBuilder().post {
    uri = "http://www.example.com"
    body = ["foo": "bar"]
    headers = [
        "X-Auth-Key": "1321d980-3ceb-11e3-b872-081196ac8a64"
    ]
}
```

See the documentation for more examples, but once we had this we never used HttpBuilder again.

Comment: look pretty intuitive, thanks for recomendation i will try it out ! right now i have a big mess mixed with .openConnection() and http-builder

Comment: how the streaming is handled?

Comment: The plugin is just a Groovy wrapper for Jersey Client.  Anything Jersey Client can do, it can do.